# make a parameter of type byte array nullable in an axis web service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis

i have a java method that is part of an web service interface and that takes a byte array parameter like this

```
public int computeSomeThind(byte[] data) {
  if(data != null) {
    // ... do what ever
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

When a generate the wsdl with axis 1.3 the data parameter will appear as not nullable. Is there a way to define this as nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by mhaller in his comment Byte[] seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is null really different that a byte[] of 0 length in this case?